# How to run ode45 for different angles

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second order differential equation. I have managed to solve it for one angle (there is a factor in the function depending on an angle) using ode45 in matlab. In my programscript there is also the same angle given as input arguments to ode45.

What I want is to solve the equation for different angles. I tested with a for-loop where I simply run through ode45 for given angles (as input arguments) and this plots out different curves like it should. 
However I'm not really sure how correct it is since I have not changed the angle in the function that ode45 solves for.

So the question is how I for each loop also change the angle inside my function.

Comment: Can you share a meaningful example of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is really related to passing parameters to a function used by `ode45`. Your function that defines the right hand side of your ODE should take the angle as an input parameter and should be of the form

```
f(t,y,angle)
```

You should then wrap this function inside another function within your `for` loop that changes the angle with each iteration. For example:

```
for angle=linspace(0,pi,10)
    odefun = @(t,y) f(t,y,angle);
    [t_out, y_out] = ode45(odefun,[t0, tf],y0);
    plot(t_out,y_out)
end
```

Also see [this document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) from Mathworks on parameterizing functions.

Comment: Thank you! This gives similar plots but slightly different which I guess does the trick.:)